# How to use natsort in python to sort folder names?

Tags: python, natsort

I have three folders, which names are `["-folder2-", "-folder1-", "=Folder-"]`.

When i use 'sorted' or in Window, it returns `["-folder-", "-folder1-", "-folder2-"]`.
But using natsort, it returns `["-folder1-", "-folder2-", "-folder-"]`.

I want to get same result by using natsort
How can i do it?

```
a = ["-folder1-", "-folder2-", "-folder-"]
import natsort
sorting = natsort.natsorted(a, alg = natsort.ns.PATH | natsort.ns.LOCALE | natsort.ns.IGNORECASE)
print(sorted(a)) #---> ["-folder-", "-folder1-", "-folder2-"]
print(sorting) #---> ["-folder1-", "-folder2-", "-folder-"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I answer your question, first I want to explain what is going on. `natsort` is looking for numbers in your input and separating them out from the non-numeric components. The easiest way to see this is by looking at the output of the natural sorting key. (I omitted the `PATH` and `LOCALE` options because they completely mangle the output).

```py
>>> import natsort
>>> ns_key = natsort.natsort_keygen(alg=natsort.IGNORECASE)
>>> a = ["-folder1-", "-folder2-", "-folder-"]
>>> [ns_key(x) for x in a]
[('-folder', 1, '-'), ('-folder', 2, '-'), ('-folder-',)]
```

When `'-folder'` is compared against `'-folder-'`, the former is considered to be first according to Python's sorting heuristics, so your folders with numbers get placed first.

To answer your question, we need to trick `natsort` into thinking that `'-'` followed by no numbers should be treated like the case with numbers. One way to do that is with regex.

```py
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r"(?<!\d)-")
>>> # What does the regex do?
>>> [r.sub("0\g<0>", x) for x in a]
['0-folder1-', '0-folder2-', '0-folder0-']
>>> # What does natsort generate?
>>> ns_key = natsort.natsort_keygen(key=lambda x: r.sub("0\g<0>", x), alg=natsort.IGNORECASE)
>>> [ns_key(x) for x in a]
[('', 0, '-folder', 1, '-'), ('', 0, '-folder', 2, '-'), ('', 0, '-folder', 0, '-')]
>>> # Does it actually work?
>>> natsort.natsorted(a, key=lambda x: r.sub("0\g<0>", x), alg=natsort.ns.PATH | natsort.ns.LOCALE | natsort.ns.IGNORECASE)
['-folder-', '-folder1-', '-folder2-']
```

An alternative method would be to "split" your input on `'-'`, which would have a similar effect. This is one of the things that `PATH` under the hood, but for file separators.

```py
>>> # What does natsort generate?
>>> ns_key = natsort.natsort_keygen(key = lambda x: x.split('-'), alg=natsort.IGNORECASE)
>>> [ns_key(x) for x in a]
[((), ('folder', 1), ()), ((), ('folder', 2), ()), ((), ('folder',), ())]
>>> # Does it actually work?
>>> natsort.natsorted(a, key=lambda x: x.split('-'), alg=natsort.ns.PATH | natsort.ns.LOCALE | natsort.ns.IGNORECASE)
['-folder-', '-folder1-', '-folder2-']
```

---

You may be wondering why `PATH` does not automatically take care of this. `PATH` was intended to handle oddities that arise because of file separators or file extensions. Your examples have neither, so it does not help. If the examples given here are representative, I would recommend removing the `PATH` option since it will only add runtime but give no benefit.